# log4j2 not writing into file

Tags: java, log4j2

log4j2.xml

I have checked several questions on this error but I haven't able to figure why data is not writing into log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="HzServer" 
                                 filename="logs/hzServer.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true"
                                 filepattern="logs/hzServer.log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1}  %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} - %msg%throwable%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="debug" includeLocation="true"
                         additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="HzServer" />

         </Logger>
     </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml

Config seems to be fine and even dependencies have been checked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

file
Spring boot application used in this example.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class HzServer implements CommandLineRunner
{
    LoggerContext loggerContext = Configurator.initialize("hzServer","log4j2.xml");
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HzServer.class);

    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance hzInstance;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(HzServer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception 
    {       
        ITopic<String> topic = hzInstance.getTopic("myTopic");

        topic.publish("HelloWorld");

        logger.info("Topic published");
        logger.debug("Topic published");
        logger.error("Topic published");
        logger.trace("Topic published");        
    }
}
```

Log file is completely blank when I run this program. Not able to figure out the exact problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay attention to the "name" property in the logger configuration:

```
<Logger name="com.example" level="debug" includeLocation="true" 
    additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="HzServer" />
</Logger>
```

The name is `com.example`, so, the logger retrieval in the class should be

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.example");
```

Also, remove the property `immediateFlush="false"` on the `RollingRandomAccessFile` appender. For some reasons, the file remains empty even if the logger names are correct.

And remove the line with the logger context initialization, it's not required to initialize the logger.

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = Configurator.initialize("hzServer","log4j2.xml");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: now its working fine. Only problem is, I am getting this error

2018-05-21 16:46:24,248 main WARN No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2018-05-21 16:46:24,512 main WARN No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender

Comment: Try adding the following under the `Loggers` section:

`<Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="HzServer" />
</Root>`

Maybe it will help